# Grant read and write to user for a table

Tags: sql, oracle

As my question stated.
The read and write isn't mean

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT ON TABLE TO USER;
```

Or

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE ON TABLE TO USER;
```

which of them is more close to READ and WRITE ? 
just want to understand the meaning of READ and WRITE. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding

`READ` means `SELECT`

`WRITE` means `INSERT` and `UPDATE` and `DELETE`. If a user has privilege for `INSERT` and `UPDATE`; he is having privilege for `DELETE` as well (`UPDATE` = `DELETE` + `INSERT`). Which essentially correspond the second `GRANT` query

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE ON TABLE TO USER;
```